# Turborepo/Typescript package - maintaining import structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, monorepo, turborepo

I'm developing a series of packages for TypeScript as apart of a Turborepo project. An example of the import structure of these packages would be

```
import { Test } from "package-name"
import { Test } from "package-name/Test"
```

The issue I face with this that in development with Turborepo I can only reference it like so:

```
import { Test } from "package-name"
import { Test } from "package-name/dist/Test"
import { Test } from "package-name/src/Test"
```

This is due to it not being in the root directory, but instead the `src` (or if built `dist`) directory.

Is there any way to get around this? I have tried several options in TSConfig to see if this would solve the issue, but can't seem to find any.

Comment: If you're managed to import in from just "package-name". Why you're importing same component two more times from "package-name/dist/Test" and "package-name/src/Test"

Comment: Those are just examples.  https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/

Comment: In MUI you can reduce the bundle size by import default path instead of Named import. But for Turborepo package it doesn't matter. And even for MUI it matters only in developement mode. When your app in production mode it does not matter if you're using Named import or default import. https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#development-environment . But it is better to import using default path for MUI components, atleast it will be helpful (faster to load) in development mode.

Comment: https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/sharing-code Turbo itself says just pass the package-name to import the component out of it (even in development mode).

Comment: This is just one example of the reasoning. I'm not specifically talking for MUI I'm saying it for custom packages where there would be a legitimate benefit

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure. I worked with `Lerna` and `Turborepo` for a couple of years. And as the documentation says we always import our mono packages like this `import { Test } from "package-name"`.  Please update us with an answer if you find any performance benefit while importing packages in a different way. Thank you.

Comment: I recommend you read webpack exports path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer my own question, I think the main mechanism here would be (given it's a limited number of packages) I could override the import path with my `tsconfig.json` paths in the main application that consumes that package, rather than in the package itself.

There is probably a cleaner way to do this, but it does work.

E.g.

```json
"package-name": [
     "../../node_modules/package-name/src/*",
]
```

I can now do:

```
import { Test } from "package-name"
import { Test } from "package-name/Test"
```

Instead of

```
import { Test } from "package-name"
import { Test } from "package-name/src/Test"
```